# How do I fix "unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregrateException' Occured error after project migration?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I migrated a Lightswitch project that was created in VB Lightswitch 2012 to Visual Studio Lightswitch 2015. Afterwards, when I attempt to publish the solution the following error is generated. "An Unhandled Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred. How do I fix the solution so I can publish to Azure